# Unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING Error in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to run a query in PHP and while the query has no errors itself (or so it seems), the editor sees an error in an "echo" statement. The code is this:

```
<?php
    include("include/session.php");
?>

<?php

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cvtool;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass'); // change these to your own database details
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // later, change ERRMODE_WARNING to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION so users wont see any errors
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    $department = isset($_GET['department'])? $_GET['department']: null;

    $sql = 'SELECT *
            FROM education
            WHERE school  LIKE ?;

    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array('%$department%');
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
        echo sprintf('%$department', $r['school']);
    }
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!--The viewport tag is used in order to scale the page properly inside any screen size -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title>CV Tool</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
        <!--Import JQuery from stored file -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <!--Import JQuery from Google's Content Delivery Network -->
        <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backToTop.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Big wrapper contains the whole site (header,navigation menu,....,footer-->
        <div id="big_wrapper">
            <header id="top_header">
                <a href="main.php"><img src="images/cvlogo.png"> </a>

            </header>
            <br>
            <nav class="clearfix">
                <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="main.php">Home</a></li>
                <?php
                    /**
                     * User has already logged in, so display relavent links, including
                     * a link to the admin center if the user is an administrator.
                     */
                    if($session->logged_in){

                        echo "<li><a href=\"search.php\">Search</a></li>"
                             ."<li><a href=\"myCVs.php\">My CV(s)</a></li>"
                             ."<li><a href=\"userinfo.php?user=$session->username\">My Account</a></li>"
                             ;

                        echo "<li><a href=\"process.php\">Logout</a></li>";
                    }
                else
                ?>

                </ul>
                <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
            </nav>
            <section id="main_section"> 

            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
            <tr>
        <th>Department</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['school'])?></td>

        </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
            </section>
            <footer id="the_footer">
                City CV Tool 2014
            </footer>
        <a href="#" class="back-to-top"></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that no matter how I change it, it still gives me an error. The error is at these specific lines:

```
while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
    echo sprintf('%$department', $r['school']);
}
```

The error might be just something missing or something extra that I put without realizing it. I know the code is about a very specific case, but still any help is appreciated.

Comment: Missing a quote `WHERE school  LIKE ?;` - Notice syntax highlighting?

Comment: Yeah I noticed it now. The editor I'm using didn't show that for some reason so it didn't occur to me that the error was there.

Comment: Which editor are you using?

Comment: PHP Designer 8. It usually shows the line that has an error and the syntax highlights, but I don't know why it didn't this time.

Comment: *Hm,* bizarro. Well, if and when something like this happens again; just before you hit the "Post your question" button, have a look at how Stack's syntax highlighting renders your code. Many a times, this will help and may very well answer itself right away.

Comment: I will from now on. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never close the following string variable :

```
 $sql = 'SELECT *
         FROM education
         WHERE school  LIKE ?;
```

Comment: OK that was it. I didn't think to look at the query for a missing quote.